# Spread data and create new columns with names derived from multiple row

Tags: r, dataframe

I have data that looks like the following:

```
a<-data_frame(Type=c(rep("A",6),rep("B",6),c(rep("A",6),rep("B",6))),Type2=c(rep("x1",3),rep("X2",3),rep("x1",3),rep("X2",3),rep("x1",3),rep("X2",3),rep("x1",3),rep("X2",3)),Color=rep(c("Red","Green","Yellow"),8),Metric=c(rep("N",12),rep("Percent",12)),Value=c(1:24))

Type Type2  Color  Metric Value
 A    x1    Red       N     1
 A    x1  Green       N     2
 A    x1 Yellow       N     3
 A    X2    Red       N     4
 A    X2  Green       N     5
 A    X2 Yellow       N     6
 B    x1    Red       N     7
 B    x1  Green       N     8
 B    x1 Yellow       N     9
 B    X2    Red       N    10
 B    X2  Green       N    11
 B    X2 Yellow       N    12
 A    x1    Red Percent    13
 A    x1  Green Percent    14
 A    x1 Yellow Percent    15
 A    X2    Red Percent    16
 A    X2  Green Percent    17
 A    X2 Yellow Percent    18
 B    x1    Red Percent    19
 B    x1  Green Percent    20
 B    x1 Yellow Percent    21
 B    X2    Red Percent    22
 B    X2  Green Percent    23
 B    X2 Yellow Percent    24
```

I am attempting to create two columns for each `Type` in `Type` where one column corresponds to `N` and the other to `Percent`where each row contains a unique combination of `Color` and `Type2`.  In this case for example there are six combinations for `Type2` and `Color`;thus, the result would have 6 rows and six columns and look like this:

```
b<-data_frame(Type2=c(rep("X1",3),rep("X2",3)),Color=rep(c("Red","Green","Yellow"),2),A_N=c(1:6),A_Percent=c(13:18),B_N=c(7:12),B_Percent=c(19:24))

# A tibble: 6 x 6
Type2  Color    A_N   A_Percen  B_N     B_Percent
<chr> <chr>     <int>    <int>  <int>     <int>
 X1    Red        1        13     7        19
 X1    Green      2        14     8        20
 X1    Yellow     3        15     9        21
 X2    Red        4        16    10        22
 X2    Green      5        17    11        23
 X2    Yellow     6        18    12        24
```

I have tried `dplyr`'s gather and spread, but nothing seems to be working.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick is to use `unite` to concatenate the columns `Type` and `Metric`, then use that new column as the key for `spread`. I usually think about a task like this (had a few just like this at work this week) by figuring out where in my df each of those pieces of information are, such as where can I find "A" and where can I find "Percent", then how I can bring them together.

```r
library(tidyverse)

a <- data_frame(
    Type = c(rep("A",6),rep("B",6),c(rep("A",6),rep("B",6))),
    Type2 = c(rep("x1",3),rep("X2",3),rep("x1",3),rep("X2",3),rep("x1",3),rep("X2",3),rep("x1",3),rep("X2",3)),
    Color = rep(c("Red","Green","Yellow"),8),
    Metric = c(rep("N",12),rep("Percent",12)),
    Value = c(1:24)
)

a %>%
    unite("type_metric", Type, Metric) %>%
    spread(key = type_metric, value = Value)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 6
#>   Type2 Color    A_N A_Percent   B_N B_Percent
#>   <chr> <chr>  <int>     <int> <int>     <int>
#> 1 x1    Green      2        14     8        20
#> 2 x1    Red        1        13     7        19
#> 3 x1    Yellow     3        15     9        21
#> 4 X2    Green      5        17    11        23
#> 5 X2    Red        4        16    10        22
#> 6 X2    Yellow     6        18    12        24
```

Created on 2018-05-10 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: That worked perfectly thank you very much!